# GPIO inputs on raspberry pi running functions twice - using Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am attempting to make a program on my raspberry pi using tkinter in python where pressing a button (pin 27 of GPIO) turns and LED on, then a second later turns the LED off. The problem I am getting is that every time I press the button, its actually turning the LED on and off twice.

The only way I have found to solve this problem is to make the debounce time be greater than that of all the LED delays, which in my situation is not an option (I would like to make it accomplish more complex and time consuming LED arrays).

As far as I understand it, the debounce time should act to solve the issue of multiple inputs occurring very quickly.  However, it seems as though its in some capacity working so that if the function that was called has not been completed by the time the debounce timer is up, it calls that function again.  What gives?  Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from tkinter import *
Screen = Tk()
Screen.geometry ('800x600')
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup (27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup (15, GPIO.OUT)

def LEDfunction(self):
    Screen.after(500)
    GPIO.output(15,True)
    Screen.after(500)
    GPIO.output(15,False)

GPIO.add_event_detect(27,GPIO.RISING,LEDfunction,bouncetime=350)

Screen.mainloop()
```

Its worth noting that time.sleep() gives me the exact same problem.  In the code listed above, bouncetime would need to be increased (to about 1050) for the function to only flash the LED once.

Comment: use some variable ie, `busy=True/False` to control  `LEDfunction`. If function is not `busy` then it set `busy=True`, does it job and set `busy=False`.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but unfortunately not only does this not work (I have tried it), it also doesn't explain the reasoning as to why it is functioning the way it is.

Comment: it is only comment, not answer :) I don't have access to RPi to check it - but maybe `rising` takes longer time and it sends more than one event when it is rising. Try this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14105/how-does-python-gpio-bouncetime-parameter-work

Comment: Switches can bounce on the press and/or the release. If you press and hold the button, does the LED still flash twice sometimes? In your LEDFunction, looks like you delay 500 before turning the LED on - surely you don't need that first delay? Total delay in your LEDFunction is 1000, have you noticed that you seem to have to make the debounce longer than this? Try removing the first 500 and shortening the second 500 which determines how long the LED is on for. Now can you shorten the debounce time?

Comment: Barny, I understand that switches can sometimes bounce and cause multiple 'rising' events, which is what the bouncetime is for.  

Also, to clarify, its not that this function lights the LED sometimes - it does it EVERY time.  Also, this code isn't the exact code that i'm wanting to use, its just a simplified version i could make as an example.  As stated before, I have other functions that I would like to be able to accomplish that are several seconds long.  Increasing the bouncetime to that much is not really an option.  I'm really hoping to figure out what is fundamentally causing this.